# Pandas Dataframe to nested json with key as value of the column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to convert this CSV dataset to nested json in python, grouped by longitude, latitude and time but also have key of number have the nested json with key as each of the numbers

```
longitude,latitude,number,time,u10
12.1700000763,-70.2799987793,0,2023-02-01 06:00:00,-14.959579
12.1700000763,-70.2799987793,1,2023-02-01 06:00:00,-14.733505
12.1700000763,-70.2799987793,2,2023-02-01 06:00:00,-15.036199
12.1700000763,-70.2799987793,0,2023-02-01 12:00:00,-17.041065
12.1700000763,-70.2799987793,1,2023-02-01 12:00:00,-16.244131
12.1700000763,-70.2799987793,2,2023-02-01 12:00:00,-17.173492
```

running

```
data_frame.groupby(['latitude','longitude','time'])
.apply(lambda x: x[['u10']]
.to_dict('records'))
.reset_index()
.rename(columns={0:'number'})
.to_json(orient='records')
```

results in

```
[
    {
        "latitude": -70.2799987793,
        "longitude": 12.1700000763,
        "time": 1675231200000,
        "number": [
            {
                "u10": -14.9595794678
            },
            {
                "u10": -14.733505249
            },
            {
                "u10": -15.036198616
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "latitude": -70.2799987793,
        "longitude": 12.1700000763,
        "time": 1675252800000,
        "number": [
            {
                "u10": -17.0410652161
            },
            {
                "u10": -16.2441310883
            },
            {
                "u10": -17.1734924316
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I would like to achieve below such that the nested json with key "number" has key of the index as string

```
[
    {
        "latitude": -70.2799987793,
        "longitude": 12.1700000763,
        "time": 1675231200000,
        "number": {
           "0": {
                "u10": -14.9595794678
            },
            "1": {
                "u10": -14.733505249
            },
            "2": {
                "u10": -15.036198616
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "latitude": -70.2799987793,
        "longitude": 12.1700000763,
        "time": 1675252800000,
        "number": {
            "0": {
                "u10": -17.0410652161
            },
            "1": {
                "u10": -16.2441310883
            },
            "2": {
                "u10": -17.1734924316
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Could someone help me on this, I'm very new to dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your lambda function to create a dictionary in the desired shape:

```
json_out = df.groupby(['latitude','longitude','time']) \
        .apply(lambda x: {str(i): {'u10': e} for i, e in enumerate(x['u10'])}) \
        .reset_index() \
        .rename(columns={0:'number'}) \
        .to_json(orient='records', indent=4)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "latitude":-70.2799987793,
        "longitude":12.1700000763,
        "time":"2023-02-01 06:00:00",
        "number":{
            "0":{
                "u10":-14.959579
            },
            "1":{
                "u10":-14.733505
            },
            "2":{
                "u10":-15.036199
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "latitude":-70.2799987793,
        "longitude":12.1700000763,
        "time":"2023-02-01 12:00:00",
        "number":{
            "0":{
                "u10":-17.041065
            },
            "1":{
                "u10":-16.244131
            },
            "2":{
                "u10":-17.173492
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Edit: same result, closer to your original solution:

```
json_out = df.groupby(['latitude','longitude','time']) \
        .apply(lambda x: x[['u10']].reset_index(drop=True).to_dict('index')) \
        .reset_index() \
        .rename(columns={0:'number'}) \
        .to_json(orient='records', indent=4)
```